# Change python logging formatter of module

Tags: python, logging, pelican

I am running pelican.. So i have a module in which i created a logger. The parent logger ie. pelican outputs data in the format level: message..

But i want the module name to be added to the log message.. So is there are way of fomatting the message of the module like... xyz: message before passing it to the parent which outputs it to the console..

I know that you can add a new streamhandler to the module itself and add a formatter to it.. But my thought is that.. adding a new streamhandler to the module will cause the module itself to output to console. rather than the parent doing it. So what is the right way of doing it??

Answer (score 0):

If you use the recommended practice of naming your loggers like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then `%(name)s` in your format string will show which module an event was logged from.

Handlers are added to loggers, so your statement "add a new streamhandler to the module itself" only makes sense if you meant "module logger itself".

Best practice, as described in the documentation, is to never add handlers (other than `NullHandler` instances) to loggers in library code (or, in general, imported modules other than the `__main__` module). In most cases, you can add a handler to the root logger, and events logged to all the other loggers will be sent to that handler.

Comment: I understood that right.. but the parent logger has format set to: level message.

So the module name is not being displayed. Is there are way of adding the module name to the message